# How to add a Choroplethmapbox fig to graph?

Tags: plotly-dash, choropleth

I want to generate a graph with a choroplethmapbox figure.
When I use function fig.show(),it was correct.But when I wanted to create a Graph with Choroplethmapbox,it only show the map without colored polygon

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(.....)

# fig.show() no problem
app.layout = html.Div([
     dcc.Graph(figure=fig,id="test")
],style={'width': '500'})

# only show maps without colored Polygon
app.run_server()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with what you've shown. Can you show more of your code?